# `subgraphMining` package not available

Tags: r, igraph, graph-theory

Was unable to install the package ‘subgraphMining’. The error says "is not available (for R version 3.4.3)". What steps are needed?

Comment: I'm asking it because I had researched the answer to a closed question that didn't seem to get reopened even after I edited it to conform to SO rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a package named subgraphMining which you can find by searching with Google using that term. (It's not a CRAN or Github hosted package.) It's found at a book website, http://www.csc.ncsu.edu/faculty/samatova/practical-graph-mining-with-R/PracticalGraphMiningWithR.html . It does require an additional package named `igraph0` and there is an answered question on SO describing that issue. The `igraph0` package is likewise not "available" for the current version of R but it is in the CRAN archives. So you also need the development tools for your OS (Mac in my case, so XCode and the Command Line Tools).

```
siteURL <- "https://www.csc2.ncsu.edu/faculty/nfsamato/practical-graph-mining-with-R/R-code/FrequentSubgraphMining.zip"
# Since I'm not a windoze user I unzip to a local disk.

install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/igraph0/igraph0_0.5.7.tar.gz", 
     repo=NULL, type="source")
# I downloaded the package from the chapter: Frequent Subgraph Mining 
install.packages("~/Downloads/FrequentSubgraphMining/subgraphMining_1.0.tar.gz",
    repo=NULL, type="source")
library(subgraphMining)
```

It's not written particularly well. It doesn't, for instance, list any Imports or Depends in the package DESCRIPTION file and the author of `igraph` thinks that the package authors should have rewritten it to use the igraph package which is currently maintained. But I think that there is quite a bit of potential value in having its installation be possible in support of what appears to be a rather interesting set of methods described in hte book.